# Multi-objective Genetic Algorithm very slow initialize

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I'm running an optimization process using the Multi-objective Genetic Algorithm from Matlab's toolbox (R2015b). The entire optimization takes about 500 seconds to complete, however it seems that it takes about 450 seconds just to initialize. So about 450 seconds to evaluate the function the first time and 50 seconds to evaluate it the following 66000 times.
I've set the population size to 500, everything else is set to default. I'm using two objective functions, 4 non-linear constraints, 1 linear inequality constrain and 4 variables with the respective lower and upper boundaries.

Is this behavior normal when using this algorithm or am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to reduce the initialization time?

Comment: I can't show the entire code but this is how I'm calling the optimization algorithm:
nvars=4;
LB=[0.005;0.005;0.005;0.020];
UB=[MaxLength;MaxLength;MaxLength;0.095];
A=[-1,0,1,0];
b=[0];
%Options and optimization Algorithm
options = gaoptimset('Display','iter','PopulationSize',500);
[x,fval,exitflag,output,population,scores]=gamultiobj(@FocalRatio,nvars,A,b,[],[],LB,UB,@nonlin,options);

Where nonlin is a function that returns an array with four entries and FocalRatio is a function that returns an array with two entries. Everything works well, it just takes a loong time to start.

Comment: It's almost impossible to read code in a comment. Please add it in your question with proper formatting.